# Browser detection give me a fatal error

Tags: php, mysql, browser-detection

I'm using this class to get browser detection name of browser and the version and the platform version name and if is a phone or other

https://github.com/Wolfcast/BrowserDetection

and this is the code

```
require_once('BrowserDetection.php');
$browser = new BrowserDetection();print($browser); 
echo 'You are using ', $browser->getBrowser(), ' version ', $browser->getVersion();// line 79
```

but it give me a fatal error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method BrowserDetection::getBrowser()
>   in C:\wamp\www\order\main.php on line 79

i want to get this information and stored in my mysql database

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: * 2016-02-11: Version 2.3.0
 *  + WARNING! Breaking change: public method getBrowser() is renamed to getName(). on line 51

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [source](https://github.com/Wolfcast/BrowserDetection/blob/master/lib/BrowserDetection.php):

```
* 2016-02-11: Version 2.3.0
*  + WARNING! Breaking change: public method getBrowser() is renamed to getName().
```

So you should use `getName()` method instead

Comment: thank you and for other if is mobile or not and how to stored in database ??

Comment: @mohamadmohamad, looks like a question for a new post. Well, I recommend using [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: i know i want to use mysqli and in my question i ask how to add no need to open a new question

Comment: @mohamadmohamad, I'd like to see your code where you're trying to store something in database. Basically, you should 1) connect to database, 2) build an SQL query, and 3) run the SQL query by means of `mysqli_query`, or similar; then 4) disconnect from the database.

Comment: i know that my question from the class how to add in database

Comment: this my query but it didn't work        $loginquery=mysqli_query($conn,"insert into tbl_login(db_datetime,db_user,db_name,db_ip,db_browser,db_version,db_mobile,db_platform)values('$date','$username','$name','$ipaddress','$browser->getName()','$browser->getVersion()','$browser->isMobile()','$browser->getPlatform()')")or die(mysqli_error($conn));

Comment: @mohamadmohamad, a string may not contain func. calls. Pass variables instead.  Always escape the input. E.g. `$sql = sprintf("insert into tbl_login(db_datetime,db_user,db_name,db_ip,db_browser,db_version,db_mobile,db_platform) values ('$date','$username','$name','$ipaddress','%s','%s', %d, '%s')",
  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $browser->getName()),
  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $browser->getVersion()),
  (int) $browser->isMobile(),
  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $browser->getPlatform()));`. I'd've written that in the answer, if you had posted this code in your question.